# SQL Server : if statement to check if columns have been modified

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with 3 columns `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `FullName` (don't ask why). I would like to create a SQL Server trigger to update `FullName` when one of the two columns has been modified. How can I check if the columns were updated? Or is there a better alternative to this problem besides ripping it out? It is being used in many places throughout the app

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UPDATE_FULLNAME 
ON [dbo].[Person]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE (FirstName) // not sure if this is correct
    BEGIN
         declare @fName nvarchar(50), @lName nvarchar(50)
         select @fName = FirstName from inserted
         select @lName = LastName from inserted

        UPDATE [dbo].[Person]

        SET FullName = @fName + ' ' + @lName
        WHERE FirstName = @fName and LastName = @lName
    END 
END
```

Comment: Better to make a view that has the fullname and not have "data duplication"  Also you want to check for nulls. something like `SET Fullname = COALESCE(@fName + ' ' +@lName,@fName,@lName,'')`

Comment: How about using a calculated column?

Comment: Don't you have to drop and readd calculated columns to modify them?

Comment: @Hogan, thanks smart answer! I will use it but I would still like it if someone could help me with that trigger I am going to be using something similar in the future.

Comment: See the official documentation [UPDATE() (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). There is also an example.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks

Comment: What if more than 1 **row** was updated? You should work with **sets**.

Comment: @AKADER - I actually don't believe you do need to know about triggers.  I personally think they are a poor design choice in all cases.  At one point you could argue for some auditing that could be done with them, but most platforms have that as a feature or you can use stored procedures and get much more control as a bonus.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Only 1 can be updated at once

Comment: @Hogan How would I do this using stored procedures?

Comment: What can stop someone to write a query `update Person set firstname = upper(firstname)`? **R**DBMS means **Relational** and strongly **relates** to **sets**.

Comment: @AKADER - remove modify rights to the table for all users.  create a SP that has modify rights.  add all modify business rules to the SP.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev your question makes no sense -- if it is a computed column or view such a statement would give an error, if a trigger the change would be over-written.  What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need triggers at all.  `Computed column` suits your purposes well.

Because the `FullName` column is in the same table it will be simpler to use a computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] 
    ADD FullName AS (COALESCE(@FirstName + ' ' + @LastName, @FirstName , @LastName, ''));
```

[Computed Columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx)

If a column named `FullName` already exists you'll need to drop it before creating the computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] DROP COLUMN FullName;
```

Comment: This is a good approach, I thought for a computed column you had to remove and add it for every update.

Answer (score 0):

The **proper** way would be to use a **set-based** approach, taking into account that a trigger might be fired for a statement that updated **more than one row at a time** and handle the situation accordingly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UPDATE_FULLNAME] 
ON [dbo].[Person]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[Person]
    SET FullName = COALESCE(@fName + ' ' + @lName, @fName, @lName, '')
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKeyColumn = d.PrimaryKeyColumn
    WHERE i.PrimaryKeyColumn = dbo.Person.PrimaryKeyColumn
      AND (i.FirstName <> d.FirstName OR i.LastName <> d.LastName)
END
```

All the other proposed solutions so far suffer from the terrible assumption that `Inserted` will only contain a *single row* - this is **NOT guaranteed** and will cause statements like this

```
select @fName = FirstName from inserted
```

to simply select **one arbitrary row** from the `Inserted` table and **ignore all other rows** that might be present (and have been updated, too)

Answer (score -1):

If your table must have only three columns, then, I believe that this is the closest to what you want (unless you have some added uniqueness condition on the name).

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_UPDATE_FULLNAME
ON dbo.Person
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE dbo.Person
    SET FullName=FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
END;
```

Comment: This is not the answer. The question was how to check if certain column was updated.

Comment: A way to do the check, that I know is by checking inserted.FirstName<>deleted.FirstName (sign that the column has changed), but if you insisted that the table has only three columns as described, then I don't know how you can use this to apply the change to the specific rows on your tables. The problem here is to identify the row, not the column.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for everyone's help, I think I will go with Hogans approach by creating a view. Here is what the stored procedure looked like

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UPDATE_FULLNAME] ON [dbo].[Person]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN

    IF (UPDATE (FirstName) OR UPDATE (LastName))
    BEGIN
         declare @fName nvarchar(50), @lName nvarchar(50)
         select @fName = FirstName from inserted
         select @lName = LastName from inserted

        UPDATE [dbo].[Person]
        SET FullName = COALESCE(@fName + ' ' +@lName,@fName,@lName,'')
        WHERE FirstName = @fName and LastName = @lName
    END 
END
```

Comment: Why create a view? It's another object to look after. Create a calculated column instead.